# Connect a matplotlib widget using keyboard event

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

Hi I am making a small program to select data from a plot. I would like to use the inbuilt matplotlib.widgets but I am misunderstanding the basics of connecting/disconnecting to the figure canvas.

Below is an example of the code I had in mind. If I declare the cursor/span widgets outside the event manager class the widgets are launched properly. However, this is not the case within the Event_Manager class.

But how should I modify the code to launch these widgets using a key event? Also how could I disconect/reconect them, also using key events?

```
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Span_Manager(Wlow,Whig):
    print Wlow,Whig
    return

class Event_Manager:

    def __init__(self, fig, ax):
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = ax
        self.redraw()

    def redraw(self):
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def connect(self):
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.onKeyPress)

    def onKeyPress(self, ev):
        if ev.key == 'q':
            print 'activate span selector'
            Span   = widgets.SpanSelector(ax, Span_Manager, 'horizontal', useblit=False, rectprops=dict(alpha=1, facecolor='Blue'))

        elif ev.key == 'w':
            print 'activate cursor'
            cursor = widgets.Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2)

        self.redraw()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x, y = 4*(np.random.rand(2, 100)-.5)
ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

mat_wid = Event_Manager(fig, ax)
mat_wid.connect()

# Span   = widgets.SpanSelector(ax, Span_Manager, 'horizontal', useblit=False, rectprops=dict(alpha=1, facecolor='Blue'))
# cursor = widgets.Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```